# Adding a folder from Jenkins machine into a git branch and commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('Commit Report') {
    steps {
        sh 'ls -l'
        // commit and push the generated HTML report to git
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'abc123', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
            sh """
                // some gitconfig command

                git checkout -b gh-pages origin/gh-pages || git checkout --orphan gh-pages
                // copy and add report folder into this branch 
                git commit -a -m "Automated commit: HTML report"
                git fetch origin gh-pages
                git merge -s recursive -X theirs origin/gh-pages
                git push origin gh-pages
            """
        }
    }
}
```

I have the above Jenkins script pipeline to commit generated HTML report into the branch gh-pages. At line `sh 'ls -l'`, it shows below output:

```
18:08:39  total 28
18:08:39  -rw-r--r--. 1 build 1000680000  3320 Sep  6 11:57 jenkinsfile
18:08:39  -rw-r--r--. 1 build 1000680000  3601 Sep  6 11:57 pom.xml
18:08:39  -rw-r--r--. 1 build 1000680000 10565 Sep  6 11:57 portalTest.iml
18:08:39  -rw-r--r--. 1 build 1000680000  1139 Sep  6 11:57 README.md
18:08:39  drwxr-sr-x. 4 build 1000680000    80 Sep  6 12:08 report 
18:08:39  drwxr-sr-x. 4 build 1000680000    30 Sep  6 11:57 src
18:08:39  drwxrwsrwx. 8 build 1000680000   140 Sep  6 12:08 target
18:08:39  -rw-r--r--. 1 build 1000680000   837 Sep  6 11:57 testng.xml
```

As you can see, there is a folder **`report`** at the root path of the current directory in the Jenkins machine. I want to copy that **report** folder and its contents to gh-pages branch and commit them. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm confused by the jenkins script excerpt... What is that?

Comment: It is part of my Jenkinsfile script that I used to run for my project pipeline. The one showing is the part specifically to handle git commit. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: so the script does not do what you want?

Comment: The script is not complete as I am not sure how to copy the folder from the jenkins machine to the checkout branch (gh-pages).

Comment: why can't you just use cp ?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Using Git Stash commands.**

```
stage('Commit Report') {
    steps {
        sh 'ls -l'
        // commit and push the generated HTML report to git
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'abc123', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
            sh """
                git add report
                git stash save report

                git checkout -b gh-pages origin/gh-pages || git checkout --orphan gh-pages
                // copy and add report folder into this branch 
                git stash pop
                
                git commit -a -m "Automated commit: HTML report"
                git fetch origin gh-pages
                git merge -s recursive -X theirs origin/gh-pages
                git push origin gh-pages
            """
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Using Jenkins stash/unstash steps**

Another option is to use the Jenkins [Stash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) step to stash and unstash the file.

```
stage('Commit Report') {
    steps {
        sh 'ls -l'
        stash includes: 'reports/**', name: 'reportStash'
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'abc123', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
            sh """
                git checkout -b gh-pages origin/gh-pages || git checkout --orphan gh-pages
           """
           unstash 'reportStash'
           sh"""
                // copy and add report folder into this branch 
                git commit -a -m "Automated commit: HTML report"
                git fetch origin gh-pages
                git merge -s recursive -X theirs origin/gh-pages
                git push origin gh-pages
            """
        }
    }
}
```